# Create a mutex with lock bitwise or (fetch_or)?

Tags: c++, c, locking, lock-free

If you the only atomic operations you had was [fetch_or](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_or) and release store could you create a mutex?

I think so. The classical algorithm uses `lock xchg` and an integer flag where 1 represents the locked state and 0 the unlocked state. So you atomically exchange(1) on the flag, and if the previous value returned is 0, you own the mutex, otherwise you failed to acquire it. Releasing an owned mutex can be done with just a release store of 0.

You could do the same with fetch_or(1), which would set the flag to 1 and return if it was previously 0 or 1. Crucially, just like the exchange operation, if the value was already 1, it does not modify it.

In both cases racing unlocks `store(0, release)` will either happen before the set to 1, and thus the lock is acquired by the new thread, or after the new thread has failed to acquire it. Obviously only the thread that owns the mutex can attempt to unlock it.

Am I missing something here, or could you create a mutex this way? The reason it's interesting is a fetch_or mutex would work better where the flag is just a single bit (e.g. in a pointer or integer). With the classical exchange technique you'd need a load first so you don't clobber the value, and you might need to use compare and swap instead of exchange depending what you do with the value in the mutex word. fetch_or is attractive since it would modify only the mutex flag bit in the word.

Comment: Yes, `fetch_or(1)` is equivalent to `exchange(1)` if the possible values were 0 and 1.  Note that on x86, C++11 `fetch_or` has to be implemented with a `lock cmpxchg` retry loop when you need the return value.  And yes you can use just a single bit of a larger integer.  You can do that directly with CAS to attempt to swap in `old|1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh, that defeats the purpose. The atomics library had me fooled that there was a real instruction that does an `atomic or`, returning the previous value. When of course `or` returns the result of the operation, and adding a `lock` prefix to it does not affect that. So of course it has to be emulated. That answers both my question and my motivation for asking.

Comment: `lock or [mem], reg` doesn't return *anything* except the FLAGS result.  You only find out whether the destination is now non-zero or negative, and the parity of low byte.  `fetch_or` exists because some ISAs might have that, and LL/SC machines can do it the same as any other atomic RMW.  x86 only has `lock xadd` for `fetch_add` and `xchg` for `exchange`, other stuff has to do `lock cmpxchg` unless you don't use the return value.

Comment: That's true, it's been a while since I've programmed in assembly. One could still use the FLAGS result for the mutex, if you set the sign bit in the mutex word, but only in some hypothetical architecture where it returned the value from before the instruction, not the result of `or(msb)` which the programmer already knows at compile time whenever you do `or` with a constant.